# auto "click" an anchor tag every X seconds? Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a section of my website that has 4 photos in it with arrows on the side. (It's kind of a "slider" but not.)

< [1][2][3][4] >

If you click the ">" arrow, it loads

< [5][6][7][8] >

In it's place, and so on.

```
<script type="text/javascript>
window.setTimeout("autoClick()", 500); 

function autoClick() {
// auto click function here
}
</script>
```

Is there a way I can (use something like that to) get that arrow to be "autoclicked" every X seconds so that it's an automated sliding action?

Comment: Why not call the javascript that loads the images directly?

Comment: Why not use actual image slider/carousel instead?

Comment: whatever this "slider arrow" calls when it's clicked, just call it directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with comments above, this isn't the best way to achieve what you want (because you should just call the javascript method for ">" directly).

If you're really set on doing it (or you're actually going to a new page by clicking that arrow) then with jQuery:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('a:contains(">")').click();
}, 1000);
```

*Note: I'm assuming that your arrow is an `<a>` tag containing a `>`. Set the selector accordingly.*

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not entirely my project, and the way it was set up was a way where I can't use the carousel in this particular instance :/

fortunately you gave me an aswer that works! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try this

```
setTimeinterval(function() {
$("a.link").trigger('click',function() {
//Do your stuff
})
},1000)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer his question, and the code doesn't make sense.  In this code, if we ignore the imaginary function `setTimeinterval`, you are applying a click handler to anchors with class `link` every second.